# php has been upgraded and all links show the index page, but the link titles display the correct format

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, php-5.4, register-globals

I'm trying to debug an older php site (from about 4-5 years ago), and php was recently upgraded on the server.

I've seen this issue before, but I cannot recall how I resolved it.

Basically the homepage shows up perfectly fine, but none of the page links are working or directing to the correct pages. For example:

.../index.php?page=latestadditions

.../index.php?page=usercat&catid=32

All links maintain the homepage content, but the browser URL path shows the correct link names.

As you can probably tell, there are MySQL queries that are resolving the URLs to dictate which page should display.

I've checked the server error logs for page requests and there are no errors being outputted. I also have a function:

```
function dbError($query,$error){
$page1=$_GET["page"];
$action1=$_GET["action"];
$dest=getConfigValue("logs");
$error="Database error on page-->$page1-- while doing action--->$action1<--- on date".date("d/m/Y")."-------->using query [$query]\n";
error_log($error,3,"dberrors.txt");
die ("Database error<!-- using query [$query] -->.System admin has been notified.  Please try again later.");

}
```

But there is no output going to the dberrors.txt..

I know the database connection is working because the record counts are being pulled into my categories and no MySQL errors are being throw. I am also checking

```
if(!$connect) dbError("Couldn't connect to MySQL Server","$mysqluser to db $dbname");
```

For some reason I believe this has to do with folder permissions problems, but I could be way off.

Thanks for any tips you can throw this way.

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked the web server error log?

Comment: Folders? What folders? You're not using any filesystem operations, so there shouldn't be any folders in play.

Comment: AlexP, yes, checked the web server log. No errors are showing. Lajos I believe is no the right track and I am modifying the .htaccess to see if I can override the php settings on the newer version.

Comment: Can you specify php version before and after upgrade.

Comment: from my thinking it would be a function/method within the app that isn't playing ball with the newer php. if everything worked before the upgrade, then its the app. try a `debug_backtrace()` to see what is being called. i couldn't see php or mysql being at fault, they do what they're told

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should turn on register_globals in php.ini or .htaccess depending on your server support.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was the problem. I wasn't able to add the directive successfully to .htaccess so I added it to php.ini like so: register_globals = true  SOLVED, bot not secure !!